# Get Directories Names Only

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have a directoy X that has say 500 subdirectories.  What I need is a quick way to just get *only* my directory and the names of these 500 subdirectories in my X directory (so, no Mode, no LastWriteTime or anything else, just the name) and pipe it to a file.

So, for example, I have this:

```
-X
 |+Dir1
 |+Dir2
 |+Dir3
 |
 ...
 |+Dir500
```

What I want to get piped to a txt file is this

```
X/Dir1
X/Dir2
X/Dir3
...
X/Dir500
```

How can I do this using PowerShell or CommandLine?
I am using Windows 7 and PowerShell 4.0
Thanks,

Comment: Hi, what have you written so far ? The answer involves one of the first commands you learn in PowerShell : `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` will do the same thing as `dir` in command-line:  it gets whatever is in your directory.  You're looking only for directories.  PS v3 and up has this built-in by using the flag of `-directory`.  In older PowerShell versions, you can pipe your `Get-ChildItem` to a `Where{$_.PSIsContainer` to get directories and then pipe that to `select Name` to just get the names of the directories, not their full paths (e.g. "Dir1" vs. "X:\Dir1").  If you want the full path, use `select FullName`.  Assuming you want that as a CSV, pipe that to `Export-Csv` followed by the name of the CSV you're creating, such as `DirectoriesInX.csv` and if you don't want the type information, add the flag of `-NoTypeInformation`.

## PowerShell v3 and up:

```
Get-ChildItem "X:\" -directory | Select FullName | Export-Csv "DirectoriesInX.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

## PowerShell v2 and below:

```
Get-ChildItem "X:\" | Where{$_.PSIsContainer} | Select FullName | Export-Csv "DirectoriesInX.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4):

I would have not used `-Recurse` based on requirement.

Moreover, OP wants to pipe output to a file :

```
(Get-ChildItem "X" -Directory).FullName | Out-File c:\myList.txt
```

*The `-Directory` switch is only available from PS3.*

*The `-Recurse` switch would go as deep as possible in the tree and list all folders*